# Issue generating multiple occurrence with Fare/Xeger

Tags: c#, regex, string

First time I use Fare project to generate string according to regex expression.

The regex string "a{1,5000}" should match sequences of "a" between 1 and 5000 characters long. 
The same regex string used with the class Xeger should generate a sequence of strings between 1 and 5000 characters long.

This very simple code generate "a{1,5000}" 100 times.

```
string regex = "a{1,5000}";           
Xeger xeger = new Xeger(regex, new Random());
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    Console.Write(i + "-" + xeger.Generate() + " ");
```

Because I specified {1,5000} I would expect that at least some string would be extremely long but no, this is what I get:

> 0-aaa 1-aa 2-aa 3-a 4-aaa 5-a 6-aaa 7-a 8-a 9-a 10-aaa 11-aa 12-aa 13-aa 14-a 15-aa 16-aa 17-aaaaaaaaaaaa 18-a 19-a 20-aaa 21-aaa 22-a 23-a 24-aaaa 25-a 26-aaaaaaaaa 27-aaa 28-a 29-a 30-aaa 31-aaaa 32-a 33-aaa 34-a 35-aaa 36-aaaa 37-a 38-a 39-aa 40-aa 41-a 42-aa 43-a 44-a 45-aaa 46-a 47-aa 48-aaa 49-aa 50-a 51-a 52-a 53-a 54-a 55-a 56-aaaaa 57-aa 58-a 59-a 60-a 61-aa 62-a 63-a 64-a 65-aa 66-aaaa 67-aa 68-aa 69-aa 70-a 71-a 72-a 73-a 74-a 75-aa 76-aa 77-aa 78-aaa 79-a 80-aaa 81-aa 82-aa 83-aa 84-a 85-a 86-a 87-aa 88-aa 89-aaaa 90-a 91-aaa 92-aaa 93-aa 94-aa 95-a 96-aaa 97-a 98-a 99-aaaa

As you can see the longest occurrence is 12 characters long. Where is the issue?

Comment: Could you provide `Xeger` class (esp. `Generate` method), please?

Comment: Fare project, where is defined, Xeger class and Generate method is here: [https://github.com/moodmosaic/Fare](https://github.com/moodmosaic/Fare)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `Xeger` is randomly selecting possible transitions at each step and then appending the string matching that transition to the result. For your regex, once the matching string has 1 `a`, there are two possible allowed transitions: "Add another `a`" or "End of string".

We could consider this as flipping a coin:

- heads = add another `a`
- tails = end of string

In order to get say a string of 100 `a`s as the result, it would be like flipping a coin and getting 100 heads in a row - a very unlikely event. As you can see, the longer the string of `a`s, the less likely it is to occur!

Comment: oh! It looks to me a very strange behavior... but ok :( Thanks a lot